# Update sequence for specific condition - Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table:

table1

```
u_a_id      element_id       my_seq
1           HI01-01          1
1           HI01-02          1
1           HI02-01          1
1           HI02-02          1
1           HI02-03          1
1           HI02-04          1

2           HI01-01          1
2           HI01-02          1
2           HI02-01          1
2           HI02-02          1
2           HI02-03          1
2           HI02-04          1
2           HI03-02          1
2           HI03-03          1
2           HI05-04          1
2           HI05-05          1
```

I need to update `my_seq` if counter in HI**01** changes to HI**02** for each u_a_id.

The output would look like:

```
u_a_id      element_id       my_seq
1           HI01-01          1
1           HI01-02          1
1           HI02-01          2
1           HI02-02          2
1           HI02-03          2
1           HI02-04          2

2           HI01-01          1
2           HI01-02          1
2           HI02-01          2
2           HI02-02          2
2           HI02-03          2
2           HI02-04          2
2           HI03-02          3
2           HI03-03          3
2           HI05-04          4
2           HI05-05          4
```

Is there a way in Oracle SQL to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `substr()`?

```
select t.*, to_number(substr(element_id, 3, 2)) as my_seq
from t;
```

A second approach is to use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by u_a_id order by substr(element_id, 1, 4)) as my_seq
from t;
```

You can use `merge` if you want to actually update the data:

```
merge into t using
      (select t.*,
              dense_rank() over (partition by u_a_id order by substr(element_id, 1, 4)) as new_my_seq
       from t
      ) s
      on s.u_a_id = t.u_a_id and s.element_id = st.element_id
when matched then update
    set t.my_seq = s.new_my_seq;
```

Comment: `substr()` is not what the OP wants. If you inspect the `element_id` column, towards the end, you will see the values jump from HI03 to HI05 (there is no HI04), but the `my_seq` values don't have gaps. `dense_rank()` is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give you exactly which you are looking for :

```
select u_a_id, 
element_id, 
dense_rank() over (order by substr(element_id,1,4)) as my_seq
from tab1 
order by u_a_id,element_id;
```

Output:

```
U_A_ID  ELEMENT_ID  MY_SEQ
1       HI01-01     1
1       HI01-02     1
1       HI02-01     2
1       HI02-02     2
1       HI02-03     2
1       HI02-04     2
2       HI01-01     1
2       HI01-02     1
2       HI02-01     2
2       HI02-02     2
2       HI02-03     2
2       HI02-04     2
2       HI03-02     3
2       HI03-03     3
2       HI05-04     4
2       HI05-05     4
```

Comment: Can you answer this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56423159/update-sequence-in-table-oracle

Comment: Also, if I don't do partition by u_a_id, would it still work?

Comment: yes you can also do it with partition by u_a_id but you have to use order by clause with substr(element_id,1,4) as it defines the rank number on the basis of order by clause.